# how to serialize case classes with traits with jsonspray

Tags: scala, spray, spray-json

I understand that if I have:

```
case class Person(name: String)
```

I can use

```
object PersonJsonImplicits extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val impPerson = jsonFormat1(Person)
}
```

and thus serialize it with:

```
import com.example.PersonJsonImplicits._
import spray.json._
new Person("somename").toJson
```

however what If i have

```
trait Animal
case class Person(name: String) extends Animal
```

and I have somewhere in my code

```
val animal = ???
```

and I need to serialize it and I want to use json spray

which serializer should I add I was hoping to have something like:

```
object AnimalJsonImplicits extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val impAnimal = jsonFormat???(Animal)
}
```

where maybe I needed to add some matcher in order to check of what type is Animal so that if its a person I would direct it to person but found nothing... was reading https://github.com/spray/spray-json  and don't understand how to do that..

so how can I serialize the set of

```
trait Animal
case class Person(name: String) extends Animal
```

with json spray?

Comment: If you're not bound to JSON spray, you can use [uPickle](http://www.lihaoyi.com/upickle-pprint/upickle/) which will handle this case automatically for you.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have a couple options:

#### Option 1

Extend `RootJsonFormat[Animal]` and put your custom logic for matching different types of `Animal`:

```
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

trait Animal   
case class Person(name: String, kind: String = "person") extends Animal

implicit val personFormat = jsonFormat2(Person.apply)   
implicit object AnimalJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Animal] {
  def write(a: Animal) = a match {
    case p: Person => p.toJson
  }
  def read(value: JsValue) = 
    // If you need to read, you will need something in the 
    // JSON that will tell you which subclass to use
    value.asJsObject.fields("kind") match {
      case JsString("person") => value.convertTo[Person]
    }
}

val a: Animal = Person("Bob")
val j = a.toJson
val a2 = j.convertTo[Animal]
```

If you paste this code into the Scala REPL you get this output:

```
a: Animal = Person(Bob,person)
j: spray.json.JsValue = {"name":"Bob","kind":"person"}
a2: Animal = Person(Bob,person)
```

[Source](https://github.com/spray/spray-json#providing-jsonformats-for-other-types)

#### Option 2

Another option is to supply implicit `jsonFormat`s for `Person` and any other subclasses of `Animal` and then write your serialize code like so:

```
def write(a: Animal) = a match {
  case p: Person => p.toJson
  case c: Cat => c.toJson
  case d: Dog => d.toJson
}
```

[Source](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/spray-user/n2LLO2wDuBo/nwDqHjh_FzsJ)

Comment: trait Animal 
"{" is missing

Comment: @MikhailZaretsky - it is valid Scala syntax to omit trait and class bodies when they are not required. This code compiles, no '{' required.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with extending `RootJsonFormat`. An examples can be found from [here](https://medium.com/rahasak/json-handling-in-scala-spray-json-afbab0e9eaba).